# How to speed up android image compilation

Tags: android, compilation, continuous-integration

I build android ICS image for x86, i use make installer_img -j8 and compilation takes a very long time. I use powerfull machine (XEON 4 cores, 8 Threads, 16GB of memmory). 
I use CCACHE, but when i ran compilation i must wait 5 mimutes to begun "core of compilation".
After that compilation process run java and I must wait again.

This is seen like that:
make installer_img -j8

1. Table (type of system, target etc.) = 5 minutes
2. Compilation (CCACHE) = 20 minutes
3. java, perl, python scripts = 20 minutes
4. integrate components to installer.img = 20 minutes

I use make deep-clean before every compilation and i don't want give up this step.

How to speed up steps 1, 3 and 4? Any ideas?

I tested this on Intel Sandy Bridge E - 6 cores, 12 threads, but this machine slighty accelerate 1st, 2nd and 4th step...
EDIT: I use 32GB of ram on this machine.

Comment: how about using ramdisk, and copying the whole project onto ramdisk and then build

Comment: Yes I tried and i will install more memory in my servers to speed up. But i think about other way. :)

Answer (score 1):

RAM, it's all about the RAM as far as I can tell after you have a certain CPU which you have.

See: https://plus.google.com/113702637309752822154/posts/GWN55ZdGmxe

Specifically stating:

> Speeds up ICS builds

Also: http://www.tabletroms.com/index.php/2011/10/23/getting-ready-to-build-ics-from-android-source-code-heavy-duty-machines-required/

and

http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/10/24/0016241/android-ics-will-require-16gb-ram-to-compile

Where both state Android ICS will "require" 16. Recommended RAM is more like 24GB.

Comment: I tested configuration with SB-E and 32GB and compilation time wasn't satisfactory for me. ;(

Comment: That's surprising. You are using Linux?

Comment: Yes, I use Ubuntu Linux 11.04 64bit.